# Find and show all unique ID's where second column entries are all duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to look for id's, where for that ID, all the entries in the second column are duplicate and exist under one or more other id's. This means I am not simply looking for whether having (id2) => 2.

If this is the input.

```
id   id2    
 1    44          
 1    44      
 1    44      
 2    44      
 2    44          
 2    44    
 2    44
 2    46    
 3    42      
 3    44          
 3    44          
 4    55    
 4    55          
 4    55          
 4    55
```

The output should be:

```
id   id2    
 1    44          
 1    44      
 1    44
```

Because all the entries under id2 also exist in id #2. Id #3 is not in the output because only some of the entries match another id, the output should only give the entries where all the id2 entries match another, regardless of how many entries it has.

I am using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Why ` 4    55 ` not exists in the result?

Comment: What do you mean "is duplicate"?

Comment: Because there is no other id that three 55 entries.  With is duplicate I mean that the all the entries in ID2 for that ID, are also existing in a different ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to count the number of unique ids for each `id2`.  If you are satisfied with just the `id` values:

```
select t.id
from t join
     (select id2, count(distinct id) as numids
      from t
      group by id2
     ) t2
     on t.id2 = t2.id2
group by t.id
having min(numids) > 1;
```

I'm not sure what the value is of getting the original values.  A simple way to get them is to add `group_concat(id2)` to the outer `select`.

If you mean that all the `id2` values for `id` *are the same and appear with other ids*, then add `having count(distinct id2)` to the `having` clause.

Comment: You geniuses are fast, let me try this.

Comment: I have tried a few examples and they all check out, awesome work.

Comment: Small additional question, say I'd also be interested in seeing how many have at least 80% of id2's as duplicate, i.e. I have ID #1 with ID2 numbers 3, 4, 5, and 6 and I have ID #2 with numbers 3, 4, 5 and 8, then in this case it would count it as 80% is duplicate. Is this a difficult addition to do?

Comment: @Dechesne . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  Be very clear on how you describe the problem (and what 80% really means).

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery

```
select * from table1 as t1 
where exists (select 1 from table2 as t2 where t1.id=t2.id group by id2 having count(distinct id)>=2)
```

Comment: You geniuses are fast, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id 
IN(SELECT id FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY id,id2)a
GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id)=1);
```